# Inject Date or LocalDate into SQL query via jdbcTemplate.query?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, java-time

I had a simple query like:

```sql
select * from sometable where date = ?
```

I injected a LocalDate into query:

```java
jdbcTemplate.query(QUERY, date);
```

Everything worked fine. After I moved my project with IDE to another PC, without any alterations, it started to throw exception:

```
nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.time.LocalDate. 
Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
```

I can use a workaround via converting LocalDate to Date:

```java
jdbcTemplate.query(QUERY, java.sql.Date.valueOf(date));
```

but it does not seem right to me: I want to know the reason.
What I checked so far:

1. PostgreSQL version is the same (BTW tried upgrading to 14)
2. JDK version is the same
3. POM dependency for PostgreSQL is the same.

Comment: Which version of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: Version from POM dependency: 42.2.24.jre7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.time.LocalDate` has been available since Java-8 whereas your JDBC driver is based on Java-7, and hence the problem. Upgrade the JDBC driver to the latest one (following) or at least to the one supporting minimum Java-8.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.2.24</version>
</dependency>
```

**Note:** The `java.util` Date-Time API and its children are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using latest version of postgresql dependency in my POM.xml, but problem still exists. Can it be that my project is using other version implicitly?

Comment: @IlyasSaitov - 42.2.24.jre7 is meant for Java-7.

Comment: After several hours of research, after trying different PostgreSQL versions and different versions of JDBC drivers I found that wrong version of driver was somehow cached (?) and implicitly used in my project. I found all the packages of different versions in my local repository, cleaned them up, removed driver from pom.xml, made clean reinstall of PostgreSQL. After that I added driver version 42.2.24, updated Maven dependencies and redeployed project. That solved my question.